# How do I deploy to nodejitsu while depending on node-sass?

Tags: node.js, compilation, nodejitsu, node-sass

I am trying to deploy my [ChucK Demos](https://github.com/aknuds1/chuckdemos/tree/hapi) application to Nodejitsu, but am stuck due to node-sass 1.2.3 not compiling on their platform (SunOS). Can I work around this problem somehow?

Error looks like this:

```
./src/libsass/json.cpp:159:18: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef uint32_t uchar_t'
/usr/include/sys/types.h:98:23: error: 'uchar_t' has a previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned char uchar_t'
../src/libsass/json.cpp: In function 'int utf8_write_char(uchar_t, char*)':
../src/libsass/json.cpp:299:3: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
../src/libsass/json.cpp:299:3: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
../src/libsass/json.cpp:299:3: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
../src/libsass/json.cpp:305:25: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
../src/libsass/json.cpp:310:25: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
../src/libsass/json.cpp: In function 'void to_surrogate_pair(uchar_t, uint16_t*, uint16_t*)':
../src/libsass/json.cpp:351:3: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
../src/libsass/json.cpp:351:3: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
../src/libsass/json.cpp: In function 'void emit_string(SB*, const char*)':
../src/libsass/json.cpp:1214:42: error: cannot convert 'uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}' to 'uchar_t* {aka unsigned char*}' for argument '2' to 'int utf8_read_char(const char*, uchar_t*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, node-sass won't compile on Nodejitsu at this point in time, since GCC 4.6 is installed on Nodejitsu, whereas node-sass requires GCC 4.7+.